# Overpass-API get all countries names in a specific language

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm new to overpass-api and I cannot wrap my head around the QL syntax.

I want to query all country names for a specific language, for example german.

There is a easy solution for csv output just putting (name="de") after the csv statement.

But if I try to solve this with json output, i get the whole data back.

Is there a discord channel or something to ask such questions?

`[out:json][timeout:25]; relation["admin_level"="2"][boundary=administrative][type!=multilinestring]["name:de"="*"]; out;`

I just need the name and maybe also the ISO name like "GB".

So I need a way to filter the tags?

Answer (score 1):

As any other tag, just include it in the wanted CSV columns `"name:de"`

```
[out:csv(::id, "name:de", "\t")]
[timeout:25];

relation["admin_level"="2"][boundary=administrative]["name:de"][type!=multilinestring];

out;
```

Try it: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1ARU

> ```
> @id   name:de     
> 9407  Andorra 
> 14296 Slowakei    
> 16239 Österreich  
> 21335 Ungarn  
> 28699 Georgien    
> 36989 Staat Vatikanstadt  
> 49715 Polen   
> 49898 Kambodscha  
> 49903 Laos    
> 49915 Vietnam 
> 50046 Dänemark    
> 50371 Myanmar 
> 51477 Deutschland 
> 51684 Tschechien  
> 51701 Schweiz 
> 52411 Belgien 
> 52822 Schweden    
> 52939 Färöer  
> 53292 Albanien    
> 53293 Nordmazedonien  
> 53296 Montenegro  
> 54224 Finnland    
> 54624 San Marino  
> 58974 Moldau  
> 59065 Belarus 
> 59470 Brasilien   
> 60189 Russland    
> 60199 Ukraine 
> 62149 Vereinigtes Königreich  
> 62269 Insel Man   
> 62273 Irland  
> 72594 Lettland    
> 72596 Litauen 
> 79510 Estland 
> 80500 Australien  
> 87565 Südafrika   
> 88210 Eswatini    
> 90689 Rumänien    
> 108089    Ecuador 
> 114686    Mexiko  
> 120027    Kolumbien   
> 148838    Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika  
> 161033    Mongolei    
> 167454    Chile   
> 171496    Ruanda  
> 174737    Türkei  
> 178009    Kirgisistan 
> 184629    Bhutan  
> 184633    Nepal   
> 184640    Bangladesch 
> 184818    Jordanien   
> 184840    Syrien  
> 184843    Libanon 
> 186382    Bulgarien   
> 192307    Griechenland    
> 192734    Nordkorea   
> 192756    Algerien    
> 192757    Tunesien    
> 192758    Libyen  
> 192763    Mauretanien 
> 192774    Gambia  
> 192775    Senegal 
> 192776    Guinea-Bissau   
> 192777    Sierra Leone    
> 192778    Guinea  
> 192779    Elfenbeinküste  
> 192780    Liberia 
> 192781    Ghana   
> 192782    Togo    
> 192783    Burkina Faso    
> 192784    Benin   
> 192785    Mali    
> 192786    Niger   
> 192787    Nigeria 
> 192789    Sudan   
> 192790    Zentralafrikanische Republik    
> 192791    Äquatorialguinea    
> 192793    Gabun   
> 192794    Republik Kongo  
> 192795    Demokratische Republik Kongo    
> 192796    Uganda  
> 192798    Kenia   
> 192799    Somalia 
> 192800    Äthiopien   
> 192801    Dschibuti   
> 192830    Kamerun 
> 195266    Namibia 
> 195267    Angola  
> 195269    Burundi 
> 195270    Tansania    
> 195271    Sambia  
> 195272    Simbabwe    
> 195273    Mosambik    
> 195290    Malawi  
> 196240    Usbekistan  
> 214626    Tadschikistan   
> 214665    Kasachstan  
> 214885    Kroatien    
> 218657    Slowenien   
> 223026    Turkmenistan    
> 252645    Bolivien    
> 270009    Guernsey    
> 270056    China   
> 272644    Venezuela   
> 285454    Britische Jungferninseln    
> 286393    Argentinien 
> 287072    Uruguay 
> 287077    Paraguay    
> 287082    Suriname    
> 287083    Guyana  
> 287666    Nicaragua   
> 287667    Costa Rica  
> 287668    Panama  
> 287670    Honduras    
> 287827    Belize  
> 288247    Peru    
> 295480    Portugal    
> 296961    Eritrea 
> 299133    Island  
> 303427    Afghanistan 
> 304716    Indien  
> 304751    Indonesien  
> 304934    Irak    
> 304938    Iran    
> 305092    Jemen   
> 305095    Katar   
> 305099    Kuwait  
> 305138    Oman    
> 305142    Osttimor    
> 307573    Pakistan    
> 307584    Saudi-Arabien   
> 307756    Südkorea    
> 307763    Vereinigte Arabische Emirate    
> 307787    Zypern  
> 307823    Dominica    
> 307828    Dominikanische Republik 
> 307829    Haiti   
> 307833    Kuba    
> 307866    Papua-Neuguinea 
> 364066    Armenien    
> 364110    Aserbaidschan   
> 365307    Malta   
> 365331    Italien 
> 367988    Jersey  
> 378734    Bahrain 
> 382313    Japan   
> 443174    Philippinen 
> 447325    Madagaskar  
> 449220    Taiwan  
> 535774    Kap Verde   
> 535790    Komoren 
> 535828    Mauritius   
> 535880    São Tomé und Príncipe   
> 536765    Seychellen  
> 536773    Malediven   
> 536780    Singapur    
> 536807    Sri Lanka   
> 536899    St. Kitts und Nevis 
> 536900    Antigua und Barbuda 
> 537257    Montserrat  
> 547469    Die Bahamas 
> 547479    Turks- und Caicosinseln 
> 547511    Barbados    
> 550725    St. Vincent und die Grenadinen  
> 550727    Grenada 
> 550728    St. Lucia   
> 555017    Jamaika 
> 555717    Trinidad und Tobago 
> 556706    Neuseeland  
> 571178    Kiribati    
> 571747    Fidschi 
> 571771    Marshallinseln  
> 571802    Föderierte Staaten von Mikronesien  
> 571804    Nauru   
> 571805    Palau   
> 1124039   Monaco  
> 1155955   Liechtenstein   
> 1278736   Gibraltar   
> 1311341   Spanien 
> 1428125   Kanada  
> 1473946   Israel  
> 1473947   Ägypten 
> 1520612   El Salvador 
> 1521463   Guatemala   
> 1558556   Niue    
> 1656678   Südsudan    
> 1741311   Serbien 
> 1857436   Salomonen   
> 1872673   Samoa   
> 1889339   Botsuana    
> 1964272   "St. Helena, Ascension und Tristan da Cunha"    
> 1983628   Südgeorgien und die Südlichen Sandwichinseln    
> 1993208   Bermuda 
> 1993867   Britisches Territorium im Indischen Ozean   
> 2067731   Thailand    
> 2088990   Kosovo  
> 2093234   Lesotho 
> 2103120   Brunei  
> 2108121   Malaysia    
> 2171347   Luxemburg   
> 2177161   Anguilla    
> 2177246   Vanuatu 
> 2177266   Tuvalu  
> 2184073   Grönland    
> 2184233   Cookinseln  
> 2185366   Kaimaninseln    
> 2185374   Falklandinseln  
> 2185375   Pitcairninseln  
> 2186600   Tokelau 
> 2186665   Tonga   
> 2202162   Frankreich  
> 2323309   Niederlande 
> 2361304   Tschad  
> 2528142   Bosnien und Herzegowina 
> 2978650   Norwegen    
> 3263728   Akrotiri und Dekelia    
> 3630439   Marokko 
> 3774664   Dar Masalit 
> 5441968   Demokratische Arabische Republik Sahara
> ```